# Get index from rows with matching values in different columns

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a set like this:

```
    N1    N2
0   a     b
1   b     f
2   c     d
3   d     a
4   e     b
```

I want to get the indexes with the repeated values between the two columns, and the value itself.
From the example, I should get something like these shortlists:

```
(value, idx(N1), idx(N2))
(a, 0, 3)
(b, 1, 0)
(b, 1, 4)
(d, 3, 2)
```

I have been able to do it with two for-loops, but for a half-million rows dataframe it took hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numpy broadcasting comparison and then use [argwhere](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to find the indices where the values where equal:

```
import numpy as np

# make a broadcasted comparison
mat = df['N2'].values == df['N1'].values[:, None]

# find the indices where the values are True
where = np.argwhere(mat)

# select the values
values = df['N1'][where[:, 0]]

# create the DataFrame
res = pd.DataFrame(data=[[val, *row] for val, row in zip(values, where)], columns=['values', 'idx_N1', 'idx_N2'])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  values  idx_N1  idx_N2
0      a       0       3
1      b       1       0
2      b       1       4
3      d       3       2
```

Comment: When I run  the first command "DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future." and does nothing :(

Comment: Without more info I cannot tell what is happening

Comment: it seems to be that the == is not stable, np.equals solved the problem